# Java deconstructor

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks

How can I reclaim the memory used by an object and all of its data structures into my application memory without `System.gc()` which only *suggests* and not *necessarily perform* memory check. This also includes methods like `finalize`.

In other words, assume I have a `HashMap` and I want all the data it stores to be deleted from the memory. I normally do clean this type of collections with `clean` methods or attach it to `null` but that doesn't seem to return the memory space to the application?

***Edits***:

Let us say the following:

```
    TIntObjectHashMap<byte[]> map=new TIntObjectHashMap<byte[]>();
    //fill the map with 20GB
    map.clear();
   //Or map=null;
```

Shouldn't the 20GB goes back free? That is the question.

Comment: An object is available for garbage collection when there are no more references to it.

Comment: Thanks to whoever pointed the other question.

Comment: @BrianRoach in fact, is eligible when any alive thread can access the object. If you have A "pointing" B and B "pointing" A, and no thread can access either A or B, both objects are eligible, however they have mutual references.

Comment: @psabbate - Yes, I'm quite aware of how the garbage collector works. Circular references cut off from the GC root is a *bit* beyond the scope of this (dup) question and I really didn't see the need to mention it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically, you can't. There's nothing you can do to absolutely *force* garbage collection, and you certainly can't manually delete an object.

Learn to love and trust the garbage collector.

Comment: +1 for `Learn to love and trust the garbage collector.` :)

Comment: Jon, thanks but that seems to me a real issue with large-scale projects. I need to handle lots of data but I don't want them to hang around for long?!

Comment: Do you have any *evidence* that it will be a problem? Java is widely used in large projects. There are ways of tuning garbage collection, but even they're often not needed - the defaults are pretty reasonable.

Comment: @DotNet: The garbage collector is almost magically smart.  Trust that it won't let unused objects pile up.

Comment: @LouisWasserman thanks. I know and I trust it but I think *clear* in collections should clear the references and let the GC whenever it feels needed collect them.

Comment: @DotNet: Yes, and it does. Any collection where `clear()` *didn't* clear the references it was holding onto would be broken. However, I rarely find myself calling `clear()` explicitly anyway - I just let the collection object itself get garbage collected, usually.

Answer (score 2):

You can't force garbage collection, the only thing you can do is to call the `System.gc()` method, but it's just a hint to the garbage collector, it will not force it to do a collection